# C++ clang compiling & linking on ipad, Linker issue

Tags: c++, ipad, clang++

please may you advise how I may compile & run main.cpp while compiling and linking the my_class.cpp & my_class.h class files,please note that this is running on an iPad using the “Code” app by “thebaselab”, which has offline clang++ 13.0. developer says its possible to work using the below method, however theres no output.

I compile seperately:

```
clang++ main.cpp -c
clang++ my_class.cpp - c
```

It seems to produce the main.o and my_class.o files so I may run using:

```
clang++ main.o my_class.o
```

**This doesnt seem to run as no output, please may you advise if you can see the problem in my code or in compiling.?**

I believe there is an issue with linking these files together, as when I have the class defined in main there’s no issues.

My code base:

main.cpp

```
// Created on iPad.


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "my_class.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hey\n"; 
    my_class obj1 = my_class("test");
    obj1.display();
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

my_class.h

```
#ifndef _my_class_H_
#define _my_class_H_

class my_class
{
private:
    std::string name = "";
public:
    my_class(std::string name_tmp);                                                         // No-args constructor                    // Copy constructor
    ~my_class();                                                      // Destructor
    
    
    void display();

    
};

#endif
```

my_class.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_class.h"

// 1-args constructor
my_class::my_class(std::string name_tmp){
    name = name_tmp;

}
// Destructor
my_class::~my_class() {
    std::cout << "Destructing\n";
}

void my_class::display(){
    std::cout << name << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What if you call it like `clang++ -o a.out main.o my_class.o`, does it create executable `a.out`?

Comment: @Quimby thank you very much, I ran clang++ -o a.out main.o my_class.o then just a.out and it works on my ipad, thank you soo much. if you provide this as an anwer I will mark yours as having solved it

Comment: The `-o a.out` isn't needed, that's the default. The command `clang++ main.o my_class.o` isn't supposed to run your program, it *links* the objects files and the standard libraries to create the executable program `a.out`, which you then can run. This should be well-documented by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Quimby,

I ran clang++ -o a.out main.o my_class.o then just a.out and it works on my iPad.